# Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008

i have a function that loops untill the correct y,n answer is typed but at the end of the choice i get the error:

```
Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'YESNO' was corrupted.
```

ive had a look on google and cant realy find any relivent answers to this error my code is as below:

```
    void Mesh_equations(float a,float b,float c,float d,float e,float f){

    char YESNO[1];                                                                                  //define variables.
    int loop=0;                                                                                 //loop set to zero.
    while(loop==0){                                                                             //while loop initiated whilst loop is equal to zero.
    cout <<"\nDo you want to display your coefficients for the mesh equations...(y/n)?";
    cin>>YESNO;                                                                                 //prompt and cin.
    if ( YESNO[0] == 'Y' || YESNO[0] == 'y'){                                                           //if cin is 'Y' or 'y'
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Loop One:\n(" <<a <<")" <<"Ix + (" <<b <<")" <<"Iy = (" <<e <<")" <<endl
            <<"Loop Two:\n("  <<c <<")" <<"Ix + (" <<d <<")" <<"Iy = (" <<f <<")" <<endl<<endl
            <<setw(5)<<"  Where ;\n"
            <<setw(5)<<"A ="<<a<<endl 
            <<setw(5)<<"B ="<<b<<endl 
            <<setw(5)<<"C ="<<c<<endl
            <<setw(5)<<"D ="<<d<<endl
            <<setw(5)<<"E ="<<e<<endl                                                           ////set the field width to 5 characters.
            <<setw(5)<<"F ="<<f <<endl<<endl;                                                   //display.
        loop=1;                                                                                 //loop is 1, while loop passed.
        system("pause");
    }
    else if( YESNO[0] == 'N' || YESNO[0] == 'n'){                                                       //if 'N' or 'n', while loop passed.
    loop=1;
    }
    else{                                                                                       //if neither y or n is enterred input must be incorrect.
    cout <<"bad answer, try again\n";
    Beep (600,100);
    loop=0;                                                                                     //loop is zero, while loop continues.
    }
}
}
```

Thanks
Houlahan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because `YESNO` is an array of characters, and `cin >> YESNO;` is writing a NULL terminator to this array.

Change the declaration of YESNO to `char YESNO;`, and remove the array operators, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

If array element is assigned out of boundary of the array, then at the run time it's showing the message "Stack around the variable was corrupted". So to resolve this problem, ensure the allocated array size and the value assigned to it.

Comment: The "out of bounds" was probably caused by "cin >> YESNO", as this means "read a string". You should do "cin >> YESNO[0]".

Comment: you answer help me a lot...I was trying to solve the problem from yesterday..but could not..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Make YESNO bigger, ie 10 chars instead of 1. Null character is put after last allowed position in array and this is the cause of error.

Comment: This isn't going to prevent a corruption if someone types something longer as a response... try using a string instead http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: I agree, input can actually limited using setw like: cin >> setw(3) >> YESNO ; to allo Yes, No etc